# Visual basicWatermark adder

Tags: vb.net, winforms, watermark

I was searching for a way to make a watermark adder . 
The idea is that it loads a picture using an open file dialog and then adds the watermark on the picture or beneath it ! . I was searching if this is possible somehow
this is my code but i always get and error

```
Dim Image1 As New Bitmap(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Dim Image2 As New Bitmap(PictureBox3.Image)

Dim Result As New Bitmap(Math.Max(Image1.Width, Image2.Width), _
  Image1.Height + Image2.Height)
Dim gResult As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Result)
gResult.DrawImage(Image1, New Point(0, 0))
gResult.DrawImage(Image2, New Point(0, Image1.Height))
gResult.Dispose()
gResult = Nothing
picturebox1.load(gresult) or picturebox1.load(result)
```

i get error with both of them !

Comment: What did you search for? Here are lots of solutions, https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vb.net+add+watermark+to+image&aq=1&oq=vb+.net+add+wat&aqs=chrome.2.57j0l3j62.8920j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8, I've assuming this is vb.net btw.

Comment: Could you rephrase your request as a question?  I'm not sure what you're actually asking.

Comment: error at the last line .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`picturebox1.Load(...)` is for path strings, not images or graphics.

Try using

```
picturebox1.Image = Result
```